# Why is my global variable not recognised?

Tags: javascript, matrix

I declared a 3 X 3 matrix as a 2D array, outside of the function and the function itself finds the determinant of the array. On click, the submit button executes the determinant function. But when I declare the array outside the function it returns NaN. It works fine when I declare it within the function though.
P.S.: This is my first program in JavaScript.
         [Relevant portion of source code][1]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Solving Matrices </h1>
    <form>
      <label for="11"> 1,1 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt11" id = "11">

      <label for="12"> 1,2 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt12" id = "12">

      <label for="13"> 1,3 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt13" id = "13"><br>

      <label for="21"> 2,1 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt21" id = "21">

      <label for="22"> 2,2 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt22" id = "22">

      <label for="23"> 2,3 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt23" id = "23"><br>

      <label for="31"> 3,1 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt31" id = "31">

      <label for="32"> 3,2 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt32" id = "32">

      <label for="33"> 3,3 </label>
      <input type="text" name="txt33" id = "33"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick = "det3()"><br>
      <p id = "output"> Output here </p>

    </form>

    <script>

   var matrix =
     [
       [parseInt(document.getElementById("11").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("12").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("13").value)],  
   [parseInt(document.getElementById("21").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("22").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("23").value)],    
   [parseInt(document.getElementById("31").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("32").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("33").value)]  ];    

function det3 ()
{


 var det = matrix[0][0]*(matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][2]-matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][1]) - matrix[0][1]*(matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][2]-matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][0]) + matrix[0][2]*(matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][1]-matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][0]);
  alert(det);

}


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly because your `script` tag is above the elements `11`, `12`, etc. So when the script loads `matrix` might not have the value. But it will be able to get the values during onclick event. If not, can you post your HTML with the question?

Comment: @NisargShah — That would cause it to throw an exception when trying to access `undefined.value` so it would never define the `det3` function, so it couldn't give `NaN`

Comment: @Quentin So maybe those elements are there, but they don't have the value. Also given that `.value` is being accessed, can we be certain that it's an input? Either the user is entering the values into those input boxes or some script. But those values might not be available when the script executes.

Comment: you might want to supply more html part showing the elements with value

Comment: @ZhangBruce  I have added the HTML portion.

Comment: @NisargShah The HTML portion has been added

Answer (score 1):

it is because if you define this as global variable your script is triggered as soon as your html is loaded, therefor the value of each element is NaN, if you do a console.log(document.getElementById("11").value) you will see nothing is printed . 
you will want to grab the value only when the button is clicked so it's best to define the matrix variable inside function or do something like this if you really want to make it global.

```html
<script>
console.log(document.getElementById("11").value)
   var matrix =[];
function det3 ()
{
 matrix =[
       [parseInt(document.getElementById("11").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("12").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("13").value)],  
   [parseInt(document.getElementById("21").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("22").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("23").value)],    
   [parseInt(document.getElementById("31").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("32").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("33").value)]  ];  

 var det = matrix[0][0]*(matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][2]-matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][1]) - matrix[0][1]*(matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][2]-matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][0]) + matrix[0][2]*(matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][1]-matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][0]);
  alert(matrix);

}
</script>
```